# Interpretation of analysis of post-intervention measurements when discarding change from baseline analysis

Tags: interpretation, standard-deviation, meta-analysis, systematic-review

I am currently in the process of creating a systematic review. The review summarises the results of multiple study, which report a certain outcome measure (the distance some athletes can throw) for the intervention and control group at baseline and after treatment.

Initially, I planned to use the difference in throwing distance as outcome of interest for the review. However, some of the included studies do not report the SDs for these differences, but only the SDs for the means before after treatment.

Following [Chapter 6](https://training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/chapter-06#section-6-3) of the Cochrane Handbook for Systematic Reviews of Interventions, I tried to impute these missing SDs from by computing the correlation coefficients from other included studies that were reported considerable detail as described in section 6.5.2.8 of the handbook. However, these correlation coefficients are all between -0.5 and 0.5. In this case, the handbook suggests to just use the measurements after treatment as outcome measure.

> In addition, if a value less than 0.5 is obtained (correlation
> coefficients lie between –1 and 1), then there is little benefit in
> using change from baseline and an analysis of post-intervention
> measurements will be more precise.

My question is now how to interpret the results of such a meta analysis. If there is a significance difference I'll know that there is significant evidence to reject the hypothesis that the difference in throwing distances between athletes in the intervention group and in the control group after treatment is zero. However, AFAIK I can no longer interpret that the difference in the increases in throwing distance is significantly different from zero (which is what I would typically like as a result).

Does the quote from the Handbook for some reason allow me to get similar results for interpretations? Or how does the small "correlation coefficient" impact my interpretation?

Comment: You can meta-analyze post-treatment means and change scores in the same analysis. What I don't understand is "the difference in the increases in throwing distance is significantly different from zero (which is what I would typically like as a result)". When you have two groups, the control group is not expected to change just because they were part of the study and therefore post-treatment means and change scores should give you similar results.

Comment: @abousetta Thank you! The control group in these studies is not really a group without any treatment but with the "standard" treatment. Especially, also for the control group an improvement to baseline is expected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In general, following an intervention there are 2 main questions for efficacy: 1) Did the intervention improve the results of an outcome? & 2) Did the intervention improve the results of an outcome in comparison to a similar control group that did not receive the intervention, received placebo, other active intervention or 'standard of care'. Q1 relates to change from baseline while Q2 relates to the difference of changes from baseline or difference in post-treatment means. For the latter, the differences can be meta-analyzed together if they are on the same scale.